# Create setup File for windows application

Tags: c#, installation, setup-deployment, windows

I am three class libraries in my windows application project. And now i want to create setup file for my project. So what i did is, just create a new setup project and added my solution file. But it adds only Forms classes. so i manually added all remaining 3 class libraries by right on the setup's solution, clicked add existing project then browsed my class library. And builded the project got the exe file.

when i try to open the installed application it saying that missing dll in the project.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Setup** project you need to include **Content** files as well as **Primary output** for the Windows project.

An example of adding files can be found [HERE](http://maffelu.net/c-setup-projet/)